# Disabling authenticator, sessions, applications, log and my resources options from the Account Management Console in KeyCloak

Tags: keycloak

[KeyCloak Account Management Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ha2oN.png)

How do I disable the menus authenticator, sessions, applications, log and my resources options from the Account Management Console in KeyCloak as marked in the picture? I just want to have the Account and Password option to be available for the users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the new or the old account console?

With the new account console you may simply want to adjust the [content.json file](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/blob/latest/extend-account-console/src/main/resources/theme/keycloak-man/account/resources/content.json)

Check out [this quickstart](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/tree/latest/extend-account-console) for details

With the old account console, I guess you will need to adjust the [template.ftl](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/14.0.0/themes/src/main/resources/theme/base/account/template.ftl) in your own theme.

Note: Please be aware that this will only change the theme and users will still be able to use the APIs directly.

Comment: Thanks a lot @sventorben. I am using the newer version of the KeyCloak and as you suggested I was doing the same (commenting out the menu options in template.ftl those are not needed). I am wondering it it is possible to make any configuration from the admin console, where we disable those options.